# Get single value from linq query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am running a LINQ query with a join. I am storing subtraction of two columns in a variable `AVAILABLECARET`.

```
var query = from r in db.Roughs
join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
select new { AVAILABLECARET=r.CARET - a.CARET };
```

How do I get `AVAILABLECARET` in a variable?

**UPDATE**

I was able to figure it out the following way

```
var AVAILABLECARET= from r in db.Roughs
join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
select new { AVAILABLECARET=r.CARET - a.CARET }.AVAILABLECARET;
```

Comment: Isn't it "in a variable" already?  `query` should contain the collection of results from this.  Each result has exactly one property... `AVAILABLECARET`.  What does your `query` variable contain, and what did you want it to contain?

Comment: @David - think he forgot to call ToList() that is the issue , because without immediate execution he might be seeing query only

Comment: @PranayRana: Possibly, but that would bring into question how he's examining or validating his results in the first place.  If, for example, he's outputting `query.ToString()` somewhere then that's certainly a practice he should cease immediately.  The Visual Studio debugger would have presented the option of enumerating the results when examining the variable.  Though if that too were the case then the OP should certainly have asked about *that* instead.  I think you have a valid guess, but for the sake of future readers who may guess differently it would be great if the OP could clarify.

Comment: @David - yes that can be done..might be he is not aware of that part

Comment: I was able to get the answer as I updated it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Hemal - that is wrong way ... i suggest you just do it as i suggested because it looks like you are creating object by new and getting it property ...that is not needed at all , there is no need of new {}..placing -1 as its wrong way of doing

Comment: @Hemal you are creating objects, and then selecting the only property of the object as the very next step. That is both a waste of programming effort and a waste of runtime effort (if your query returns thousands of rows, then thousands of small objects are created that the Garbage Collector then has to dispose of). See my answer for an approach without the unnecessary anonymous objects.

Comment: @PeterB Can I do it this way? `var AVAILABLECARET = (from r in db.Roughs
                         join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
                         from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
                         select r.CARET - a.CARET).Single();`

Comment: You can, but Single() will throw an Exception if there are no items, and also if there is more than 1 item. It expects and even demands that the result count is exactly **1**.

Comment: updated my answer ...have a look

Answer (score 1):

To get single value you have to do like this

```
decimal values = (from r in db.Roughs
join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
select (r.CARET - a.CARET )).Sum();
```

or if you want to get top most

```
decimal? val = (from r in db.Roughs
join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
select (r.CARET - a.CARET )).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Try `ToList()` on your query you will get result , and make use of `IEnumerable<T>` as variable type here T get replace by type you are expecting.

---

as per your query you are doing outer join then you should try ,assuming decimal type

```
IEnumerable<decimal> values = (from r in db.Roughs
join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
select  (r.CARET -  (a == null ? 0 : a.CARET))).ToList();
```

---

it will be like as below exaple , if the type of variable is `int` then

```
IEnumerable<int> values = (from r in db.Roughs
join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
select (r.CARET - a.CARET )).ToList();
```

so my point whatever type you are expecting you can replace instead of int, if you expection decimal than it will be `IEnumerable<deimal>`

Linq query return you `IEnumerable<T>` here T replaced by type you are expcetion and you need `ToList()` function to get result and execute your query immedicatly.

Comment: You can't use `IEnumerable<int>` or `IEnumerable<decimal>` because as-is, the `select` creates anonymous objects. Either the `select` should drop the anonymous object part, or the result should be put in an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.

Comment: @PeterB - he is performing (-) minus operation on column so i am assuming its going to be numeric type like decimal, int or float ... that y i written replace it with type you are expecting ...

Comment: @PeterB - i think he forgot ToList() thats reason he is not seeing actual return list and that is the issue

Comment: @PranayRana: In order to use `int` or `decimal` you'd need to select only the value, not an anonymous object containing the value.  (Remove the `new { }` syntax.)

Comment: Is it possible to get a single value rather than `IEnumerable<decimal>`?

Comment: @Hemal - updated my answer for that you need to use Sum() function if you wan to sum all values..Please do upvote/accept if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.ToList()`, and then it may be better to not create anonymous objects, so drop the `new {...}` part:

```
var values =
   (from r in db.Roughs
    join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
    from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
    select r.CARET - a.CARET
).ToList();
```

This gives you a `List<someNumericType>`, depending on whatever type your CARET field may have.

If you need just the first value (or null if there aren't any):

```
var value =
   (from r in db.Roughs
    join a in db.Assorts on r.ROUGHNO equals a.RFNO into ra
    from a in ra.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where r.ROUGHNO == id.ToString()
    select r.CARET - a.CARET
).FirstOrDefault();
```

This produces a `Nullable<someNumericType>`, depending on whatever type your CARET field may have.

Comment: that is outer join ...there might be cause "a" comes with null vlaue..you have to handle that case also

Comment: You are right, but still I'm leaving it out because that is not what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value in a variable like this. Put this line after your query.

```
var value =query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: just want to know why first or defaut ..it is going to be list